# Encrypting strings in SQL (likely ORACLE PL SQL). Caesar Cipher

Tags: sql, oracle, encryption, plsql

I need something like the Caesar Cipher to be used in my string columns for the every value in each column. It should be made something like n+1:
ABcd012Ab -> BCde123Bc

The string characters may be null, may contain sepparators (, - etc.), they may be upper and lower case (it doesnt matter).

Finaly, it should be created as a procedure, and this procedure should be then used inside an UPDATE query.

It shold maybe look something like this:

```
Create procedure text_change(n varchar(1000))
declare @i char
declare @l varchar(100 char)
begin
For each @l in n
For each @i in @l
loop
@i = ????
end loop;
return @l;
end;

UPDATE name_of_table
SET name_of_column = text_change(column)
```

Would be very happy for any help!

Comment: [`SUBSTRING`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), [`ASCII`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ascii-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), [`CHAR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/char-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: If you want to use it in an update query, you're far better off using a function than a procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to "encrypt" alphanumerics, you might try the following. You didn't specify what you wanted done with `9`, `Z`, or `z` so I just took the next ASCII character (`:`, `[`, and `{` respectively):

```
SELECT mycolumn
     , TRANSLATE( mycolumn
                , '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
                , '123456789:BCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{' )
  FROM mytable;
```

Hope this helps.

**EDIT:** I'm not sure why I've continued to think about this, but here is a general solution with user-defined function using Oracle's `TRANSLATE()` function. It doesn't include numbers but I'm sure those would be an easy addition:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION caesar_cipher
  ( p_source IN VARCHAR2, p_offset IN PLS_INTEGER )
RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
  c_abc CONSTANT VARCHAR2(128) := 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
  v_offset PLS_INTEGER;
  v_target VARCHAR2(32767);
  v_transl VARCHAR2(128);
BEGIN
  v_offset := MOD( p_offset, LENGTH(c_abc) );
  IF (v_offset < 0) THEN
    v_offset := v_offset + LENGTH(c_abc);
 END IF;
 v_transl := SUBSTR(c_abc, v_offset+1) || SUBSTR(c_abc, 1, v_offset);
 v_target := TRANSLATE( p_source, c_abc || LOWER(c_abc), v_transl || LOWER(v_transl) );

  RETURN v_target;
END;
/
```

To "decrypt" use a negative value for the offset instead of a positive one; that is, `CAESAR_CIPHER('CDE', -2)` is the opposite of `CAESAR_CIPHER('ABC', 2)`. It strikes me as more efficient than examining every character of the source string but I've not run a test to be sure.

Comment: P.S. a more general solution (with a dynamic offset) can be found here: https://mikesmithers.wordpress.com/2016/12/09/post-truth-plsql/

Answer (score 2):

Why restrict yourself to Caesar Cipher? You could make use of `DBMS_CRYPTO` package which allows you to use Data Encryption Standard (DES)

[**Docs**](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_crypto.htm#ARPLS65682)

Firstly, get execute permission to this package from DBA.

```
SQL> GRANT EXECUTE ON DBMS_CRYPTO  TO HR;

Grant succeeded.
```

Then create a function like this.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_encrypt(
    p_source VARCHAR2,
    p_key    VARCHAR2 )
  RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
BEGIN
  RETURN UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2 ( DBMS_CRYPTO.encrypt( UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW (p_source), 
       dbms_crypto.DES_CBC_PKCS5, UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW (p_key) ) );
END;
/
```

This uses `DES_CBC_PKCS5` Block Cipher Suite.

So, when you run a query like this you get encrypted data.

```
SQL> SELECT my_encrypt('TREASURE UNDER OAK TREE',
  2                'The DBMS_CRYPTO package replaces DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT') AS
  3         encrypted
  4  FROM   dual;


ENCRYPTED
----------------------------
┐↨┐┐♣!┐ o)|┐┐┐┐┐┐┐┐
```

**Decrypt function**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_decrypt ( p_source VARCHAR2, p_key VARCHAR2  )
RETURN VARCHAR2 AS

BEGIN

   RETURN UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2 ( DBMS_CRYPTO.decrypt( UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW (p_source), dbms_crypto.DES_CBC_PKCS5, UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW (p_key) ) );

END;
/


SQL> SELECT my_decrypt( my_encrypt('TREASURE UNDER OAK TREE',
  2                'The DBMS_CRYPTO package replaces DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT')  ,
  3                'The DBMS_CRYPTO package replaces DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT') AS
  4         decrypted
  5  FROM   dual;

DECRYPTED
---------------------------------
TREASURE UNDER OAK TREE
```

You could also use it to encrypt and decrypt the columns in the table.

```
update yourtable set SOMETEXT =
my_encrypt(SOMETEXT,'The DBMS_CRYPTO package replaces DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT');

update yourtable set SOMETEXT = 
my_decrypt(SOMETEXT,'The DBMS_CRYPTO package replaces DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT');
```

Comment: This is a better solution IMO!